# How to embed a field from one database to another

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections (`_items` and `_details`), and within the `_details` database I have a field called `product_description`, how would I be able to embed that field to the `_items` database by matching the `product_barcode` field as both of the databases have that field. I am trying to get the descriptions to match the barcodes in the `_items` database

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If we're talking about two DB's rather than two collections, then where are these two DB's hosted on ? If they're hosted on mongo atlas then are those on same cluster ? what is MongoDB version ? Do you need to update docs in `_items` ?Can you provide sample docs ?

Comment: My mistake, I was meant to write collections instead of databases and I am using the latest mongodb and I am running it on Robo3t

Comment: Do you’ve to update db or just read data with that field added to docs ?

Comment: I just have to move the "Descriptions" over to the _items collection and make sure that the descriptions are correct for the items, I'm assuming as both of the collections have the _barcode field in them that we need to make use of this?

Comment: Please post a sample document structure for both the collections (_items and _details).

Answer (score 0):

This may run multiple times if your _barcode is not unique, but you can update as needed to fit your needs.

(update databaseName with the name of your database)

```
use databaseName
_details = db.getCollection("_details");
_items = db.getCollection("_items");
_details.find().forEach( function(document) {
    _items.update({"product_barcode": document.product_barcode}, {$set: 
{"product_description": document.product_description}}, false, true);
})
```

Comment: Hello, I tried this and got the message "Script executed properly. But no results to show" and both of the collections still look the same, any idea why?

Comment: I didn't see that you changed the description to product_description and _barcode to product_barcode. You will need to change these on the script

Comment: Yeah I've made all the changes but still getting the same message, strange but ill keep trying

Comment: I would double check that all the names/fields are correct with what is in your system. I have tested this on a dummy database I created and it does work.

Comment: I tried it again and started to get the following; Error:
TypeError: _details is not a function

Comment: the db.getCollection("_details"), does that work properly?